# Localize title for header in sections of UITableView with static cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a storyboard with a UITableView. How can I change the title of each section programmatically? I have defined the following class:

```
MyTableView : UITableView
```

And I don't want to implement `UITableViewDataSource`, since it doesn't make sense to implement tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: with static cells.

Answer (score 1):

You have to options here.

1. Localize your storyboard and set the title of each section header.
2. Just implement `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` and return the localized strings. You do not need to implement the entire data source protocol.

First option is preferred.

Comment: Option 1 is not possible with my solution. For option 2, I have tried just implementing that method, but it is never invoked @Leo Natan

Comment: @Matias Just checked and it's indeed called. Make sure you have set the controller's class in the storyboard to the controller class name. I can provide a demo project if you need.

Comment: I have set it but it is not being called. I have UITableViewController in my storyboard (whose class is MyUITableViewController), and inside it I have a UITableView (whose class is MyTableView).
MyTableView is the class that implements UITableViewDataSource, but the tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: is not being called

Comment: I think you have mixed a few things here. Normally, the controller is the data source and delegate of the table, but that is not a must. However, when you are using a static table view in storyboard, the controller is always the data source. Thus, you need to have this method implemented in the controller, not the table view implementation. By adding it, you will override the internal Apple implementation for static cells, which is what you want. You can get the static value by calling the `super` implementation.